# Adding an already created folder to Google Drive in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want use google drive in my android app to backup folders that contain text, image and video files.

My problem is that while I can upload each text, image and video file separately using the Drive API, I can't see a way to upload entire folders at once so that the organisation remains intact.

The organisation of the folders is as follows:

app>Projects>notes>photos/text/video

Ideally I would like to upload the folder "app" and along with all of its contents while keeping the parent/child structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Google Drive Api for Android or the REST Api ?

If you are using the REST API you can create a folder like this :

```
        private String createFolder() throws IOException {
        File fileMetadata = new File();
        fileMetadata.setName("FOLDER_NAME");
        fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

        File file = mService.files().create(fileMetadata)
                .setFields("id")
                .execute();
        String Folderid =  file.getId();
```

And then with the file id you do this :

```
File nFile= new File();

        nFile.setName("FILE_NAME");
        nFile.setParents(Collections.singletonList(Folderid));
        File file = mService.nFile().create(fileMetadata).execute();
```

The setParents is used to create the file INSIDE the parent which is the folder just created in this example.

Comment: I have been using the Drive Api for Android, but I'll give this a go anyway!